# UNV/UFF file in Python

Tags: python, file

I fail to find a package to read UNV/UFF file in Python. Pyuff package outputs this error when trying to read some files(while it works well for some other files with other kind of data) and it signals the same line that the author describes as not being a good implementation:

[image: Error]

I wonder if anyone has any idea how to solve this or knows some other package that works well

Comment: How are you trying to use that package in your code?

Comment: I love that `TODO` that the dev left right under where it happens haha

Comment: Have you tried converting the file before processing it?  You are encountering the age old ASCII vs Unicode issue.  https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Comment: @eatmeimadanish No I haven't  tried to convert the file and I truly have no idea how to do this. I would so thankful for some help!

Comment: @Alfabravo I'm really just trying to read the content of 1 set (the unique set within the file)